# How to get iPad only Customer Reviews on iTunes

Tags: app-store, itunes, review

I'm wondering if there is a way to get iPad only customer reviews for the universal application on iTunes? 
I can filter it by a version but I'd want to filter it by iPhone/iPad only.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question related to programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible... but I might be wrong with this.